# posgresql exclude zero division error results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am executing a query but for sum cases

```
SUM( CASE WHEN dismissal_kind = 'caught' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
```

this part of the code results into zero which causes zero division error.I am trying to not show result(not select) when

```
SUM( CASE WHEN dismissal_kind = 'caught' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
```

Pease help.

```
"""select distinct bowler as b,
    count(bowler)/SUM( CASE WHEN dismissal_kind = 'caught' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) from deliveries
    group by bowler; """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to remove the `else 0`:

```
SUM( CASE WHEN dismissal_kind = 'caught' THEN 1 END )
```

This returns `NULL` if nothing matches the condition.  Dividing by `NULL` produces `NULL` and not an error.

For your query however, I recommend:

```
select bowler as b,
       count(*) / nullif(count(*) filter (where dismissal_kind = 'caught'), 0)
from deliveries
group by bowler;
```

`nullif()` is another way to avoid division by zero.  `filter` is the recommended (and standard) syntax for conditional aggregation.

If you want to filter out the rows that are `null`, you can include a `having` clause:

```
select bowler as b,
       count(*) / nullif(count(*) filter (where dismissal_kind = 'caught'), 0)
from deliveries
group by bowler
having count(*) filter (where dismissal_kind = 'caught') > 0;
```

Comment: how is this showing distinct bowlers without mentioning in query??

Comment: @PravinMishra . . . This shows each bowler on a separate row of the result set because of the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, by using case when:
In my example i put the default value to 0 but you can have a default value different depending on your use case

```
select distinct bowler as b,
    case when SUM( CASE WHEN dismissal_kind = 'caught' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) <> 0
    then
       count(bowler)/SUM( CASE WHEN dismissal_kind = 'caught' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
    else
    0
   end 
from deliveries
    group by bowler;
```